# "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent" error when trying to spawn a node

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The error that I keep getting is this one: `Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent`. I have tried to take out the spawn function and it works without it. Can someone please help me ?

```
func spawnTrolls(){

    let minValue = self.size.width / 10
    let maxValue = self.size.width - 30
    let spawnpoint = UInt32(maxValue - minValue)
    Troll.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(spawnpoint)), self.size.height)
    self.addChild(Troll)
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-70, duration: 2)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    Troll.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    Troll.physicsBody? = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Troll.size)
    Troll.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCategory.Troll
    Troll.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategory.Rocket
    Troll.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    Troll.physicsBody?.dynamic = true   
}

_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnTrolls"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: The reason somebody gave you a down vote is because your question is already answered by your error message.  You only have 1 Troll,  and you try adding Troll to the scene every 1/2 second.  Since this Troll is already on the scene, you can't add it back to the scene

Comment: what can i do to add more of them then ? i want my screen to have many of them

Comment: Make Trolls in that function?  If you do not know how to make multiple sprites, you should hit up some tutorials

Comment: You need to create a new `SKSpriteNode` instance in your `spawnTrolls` function, i.e `troll = SKSpriteNode()`, otherwise you're just trying to add the same node over and over again. Also you should begin your variable names with a lowercase letter, to prevent them from getting confused with classes. Also you should probably avoid using `NSTimers` and instead use the `update:` method to coordinate repeated game logic.

Comment: Thank you dude, im sorry im such a noob at Swift, still learning :|