# Swift: Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent:

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I know why I'm getting that error, but I can't figure out a way around it. I'm trying to have objects come appear and then be removed and the player should try to tap them before they're removed, but everytime the next node is about to appear it crashes. If i declare it inside its func then it all comes out but I can't tap on it...

Code:

```
let step = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    backgroundColor = UIColor.feelFreeToColor()

    self.color = self.randomNumbersInt(3)
    self.showBars()
    self.showScore()
    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock {
        //self.color = self.randomNumbersInt(3)
        self.showSteps()
    }
    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
    let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn , delay])
    let spawnDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)

    self.runAction(spawnDelayForever)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        var location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == step {
            self.score += 1
        }
    }
}

func showSteps() {
    let createSteps = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -self.frame.height - 30 , duration: 10)
    let removeSteps = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    step.color = colors[randomNumbersInt(3)]!
    step.size = CGSize(width: 275, height: 30)
    step.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.height * 0.75)
    step.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: step.size)
    step.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Config.PhysicBodyType.Steps.rawValue
    step.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    step.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    step.zPosition = 1
    step.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([createSteps, removeSteps])))

    addChild(step)
}
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37088680/5191756).

Comment: I already seen that before posting this up, not even the same issue. I know that if i want to re add the same sknode i have to declare everything in the function, but i need to access it outside that function while it's creating and removing the sknode... @Gliderman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `showSteps` function, declare the `step` node inside it, not at the top of your code, and also give it a `name`:

```
func showSteps() {
    let step = SKSpriteNode()
    ...
    step.name = "step"
    step.color = colors[randomNumbersInt(3)]!
    // etc
}
```

In your `touchesBegan` method, you have this `if` statement:

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == step {
     self.score += 1
}
```

You want to remove that node that you have hit, but now you can just check the `name` property like so:

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location)?.name == "step" {
    self.nodeAtPoint(location)?.removeFromParent()
    self.score += 1
}
```

Please note that I am not super fluent in Swift, but I think you will probably need the `?` in your `if` statement, as it might not exist (such as if you didn't tap on a specific node).  Somebody more familiar with Swift is free to correct me.

Comment: Is it possible to access other properties like color? If I tap i want it to change color.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed It should be, I'm not able to test right now though.

Comment: Where can i find more about this? Fairly new to swift. I need to access that sknode  (WORKS THANKS TO YOU!) and have it be the same color as what it's being compared to.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed Well, [here is Apple's documentation on SKSpriteNodes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKSpriteNode_Ref/).  StackOverflow isn't really a recommendation site, but there are hundreds (thousands?) of tutorials out there for Swift which you would probably be able to narrow down in a web search with careful wording of what you are trying to learn about.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll do the searches from here.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed  No problem.